# How can I create a new column in a pandas dataframe that counts backwards the rows based on the value of another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in a pandas dataframe, based on values in another column. For each value in the existing column, I would like to count back the number of rows equal to the value itself, decreasing to zero. Below is an example of the existing and desired column.

| quarter_hour | is_longest_activation | is_in_longest_activation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 6 | 0 | 6 |
| 7 | 0 | 7 |
| 8 | 0 | 8 |
| 9 | 0 | 9 |
| 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 11 | 0 | 0 |

Edit: if there is an overlap, it should reset to the row that is uppermost, as in the updated example below
[Column A is the column I have, and I would like to derive column B]
`https://pastebin.com/M59T0ibf`[Dataset extract](https://pastebin.com/M59T0ibf)

```
UpEnergy["is_longest_activation"] = 
    UpEnergy["consecutive_activations_count"].where(
    UpEnergy["consecutive_activations_count"]==UpEnergy[
    "consecutive_activations_count_daily_max"]
    ,0)

counter = UpEnergy["is_longest_activation"].where(UpEnergy["is_longest_activation"].ne(0)).bfill().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
    UpEnergy["is_in_longest_activation"]= counter.sub(
  
 UpEnergy.groupby(counter).cumcount(ascending=False)).clip(lower=0)
```

Comment: please provide a meaningful reproducible example, empty rows are not useful to reproduce your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reversed [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) :

```
s = df['A'].where(df['A'].ne(0)).bfill().fillna(0, downcast='infer')

df['B'] = s.sub(df.groupby(s).cumcount(ascending=False)).clip(lower=0)
```

Output:

```
    quarter_hour  A  B
0              1  0  0
1              2  0  0
2              3  0  1
3              4  2  2
4              5  0  0
5              6  0  0
6              7  0  1
7              8  0  2
8              9  0  3
9             10  4  4
10            11  0  0
```

Intermediates:

```
    quarter_hour  A  B  s  cumcount  sub
0              1  0  0  2         3   -1
1              2  0  0  2         2    0
2              3  0  1  2         1    1
3              4  2  2  2         0    2
4              5  0  0  4         5   -1
5              6  0  0  4         4    0
6              7  0  1  4         3    1
7              8  0  2  4         2    2
8              9  0  3  4         1    3
9             10  4  4  4         0    4
10            11  0  0  0         0    0
```

###### updated example:

```
    quarter_hour   A   B
0              1   0   0
1              2   0   0
2              3   0   1
3              4   2   2
4              5   0   5
5              6   0   6
6              7   0   7
7              8   0   8
8              9   0   9
9             10  10  10
10            11   0   0
```

---

Alternative with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
df['B'] = (df.groupby(df.loc[::-1, 'A'].ne(0).cumsum())['A']
             .transform(lambda s: s.iloc[-1]+np.arange(1-len(s), 1)).clip(lower=0)
          )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mozway! Seems to work perfectly, but I realised I didn't entirely specify my question sufficiently. Could this be designed to deal with overlapping sequences as below?

Comment: Please edit the question, comment don't handle code formatting (or if the logic is too different, open another question)

Comment: sorry, not a frequent user of the platform - it's done - thanks!

Comment: @arj you should have tried it, it was already working like this ;)

Comment: i did, must be something else is happening on my actual dataset. but anyway, this is already a massive help. thanks a lot! and sorry for the posting confusion :)

Comment: This doesn't work for you? Can you provide the dataset?

Comment: I have posted some of the code and a data extract. Does that work? The last two columns are the ones we have discussed.